# SVN commit error: "'.' is not a working copy"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I can SVN-update and browse the repository just fine. The .svn directory exists in every folder across the checked out code tree. Only commit is broken for some reason.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Do you have SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK set in your environment, i.e. use _svn not .svn? Not sure why that would affect commit only

Comment: Did you run svn update with newer svn client, and now trying to commit with an older version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your working copy is not in the drive root but at least one folder below the drive root.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean Up menu option.

Comment: No luck, clean-up successfully on the root directory of the repository (I am assuming that's the best place to try). Operation went successful but still can't commit, same error.

Comment: Do you have externals in your svn folder? In another words, do you have svn:externals property set?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you cd or right-click the correct folder.