# svn: '\' is not a working copy ERROR

Tags: svn, subclipse

We have an SVN project which we use Subclipse + Eclipse to commit changes. We have the repository setup in the following tree:

Universe- Root (mapped to X:)
+ LFUTILS 
+ LFPROGS
+ LFUTILS
+ LF_FINS

Universe (X:) is the main directory of this SVN project, with the other folders being part of the tree. I can make changes to programs in the subfolders and commit them fine. For example if I want to commit a change in LFUTILS it works flaweless.

```
commit -m "" X:/LFUTILS/TEST_HARNESS2
Sending        X:/LFUTILS/TEST_HARNESS2
Transmitting file data ...
Committed revision 195.
```

The problem is when I have changes in more than 1 subdirectory, for example in LFUTILS and LFPROGS. If I click on the top level of the SVN project which is Universe (X:) and do a Team-> Commit I get the following error:

```
commit -m "" X:/LFUTILS/TEST_HARNESS2 X:/LF_FINS/REINS_REPORTING_INS
Path is not a working copy directory
```

svn: '\' is not a working copy

I receive the above error and the changes are not committed. From the research I've done it appears that I need to move all the files from X:\ to another folder and then do a fresh checkout in eclipse. Does this make sense? Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this other than a possible corrupt .svn file/folder?

I've tried doing a refresh, cleanup on the root (x:), as well as a couple other things but I have not tried to do a fresh checkout.

Comment: Are both `LFUTILS` and `LF_FINS` in the same working copy, or do you have multiple working copies at `X:\`? On a side note: generally it's not a good idea to use a network share for a working copy, because a working copy is personal, so you can do anything there without bother other people.

Comment: I believe LFUTILS and LF_FINS are in the same working copy since I can 'update to HEAD' right from the root (x:). Also, when I go into the root (x:) and look at the .svn folder the file called 'entries' shows all the subfolders with the word 'dir' underneath so I would assume it's all under 1 working copy. I guess my question would be is there a definite way to tell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN commit error: "'.' is not a working copy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197963/svn-commit-error-is-not-a-working-copy)

Answer (score 0):

It's caused because the working copy is at the drive root, something not supported by Subversion

I still think that it's better to develop on your own working copy (locally). It's both faster, and you don't get in the way of other. Combining different people's code is the task of the SCM software (Subversion in this case), and shouldn't be done on a network share.

Comment: When you say it's at the drive root, do you mean because of how I mapped X: as a network folder? X: maps to a folder on our developer server which is (c:\programs\<my region>) so it's not at the drive root on the server but it's at the drive root of how I mapped it to X:

Comment: its at the root of X:\, that's not supported

Comment: ok, I see what you're saying. The way x: maps to the server is as follows:

Comment: x: -> c:\CHRISSYS where CHRISSYS I believe is the working folder. To fix this would mapping x: to the c: on the server and then telling eclipse the project is in x:\chrissys seem to fix this? Instead of how I'm telling eclipse the project is located at x:?

Comment: try committing the shares instead, you'll see that that works as expected `svn commit \\server\share\path`

Comment: what do you mean by committing the shares? I can commit LFUTILS, LFPROGS, etc. Is that what you're referring to? Such as x:\LFUTILS?

Comment: I meant what I said, `svn commit \\server\share\LFUTILS \\server\share\LFPROGS` without using `X:\`. I'm not completely sure if this will fix it though.